# Need help with programming an NXTBee on a NXT Lego Mindstorm Robot

Tags: c, xbee, nxt

I am doing a project for work using the NXTBee NXT controlled by an arduino. But I'm a novice with programming. I am using ROBOTC and when I compile I am getting an error: **Calling procedure 'nxtReadRawHS' with indirect levels mismatch. Parameter: 'unsigned ubyte* pData. Expression: 'incomingData'. Type: 'ubyte'**. I know i need a .h library but when i try and put one in from another program it still is wrong. If anyone could help me please help. Thank you

Code starts here:

```
#pragma platform(NXT)

int power = 0; // Global variable for power.
int steer = 0; // Global variable for steering.
//int direc = 0; // Global variable for direciton.

void setupHighSpeedLink()
{
    // Initialize port S4 to “high speed” mode.
    nxtEnableHSPort();
    nxtSetHSBaudRate(9600);
    nxtHS_Mode = hsMsgModeMaster;
    return;
}

void ReadResponse()
{
    byte BytesRead[3]; // Array we’ll be reading into.
    nxtReadRawHS(BytesRead[0], 3); // Read the array.

    if(BytesRead[0] == '/') { // If we catch the null, read the next three things.
        power = BytesRead[1]-70; // -70 is left, 70 is right
        steer = BytesRead[2]-100; // -100 is Back, 100 is forward
        //direc = BytesRead[3]; // “0? is forward, “1? is reverse.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add the 'c' tag to your question the code will automatically get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Not sure EE.SE is the right place to ask this... maybe Programmers.SE (or perhaps even the imminent Robotics.SE) would be better?

Comment: Programming on embedded is on topic here and this reads as that to me, I am not going to mod-close it, the users might, but it seems the problem may have already been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The specific compiler error you're getting is this: You're passing `BytesRead[0]` as the first parameter to `nxtReadRawHS()`, which is a `byte`, but the compiler is telling you that the function expects a `ubyte *` (a pointer or address) in that position.

Change the first argument to either `BytesRead` or `&BytesRead[0]`; both of these expressions represent the address of the first byte in the array.